# Basic Python/Beautiful Soup Parsing

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Say I have use

```
date = r.find('abbr')
```

to get

```
<abbr class="dtstart" title="2012-11-16T00:00:00-05:00">November 16, 2012</abbr>
```

I just want to print `November 16, 2012`, but if I try

```
print date.string
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE: Here's my code**
Neither of the print pairs print the raw string, but the uncommented ones get the correct tags

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen("some-url-path")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
calendar = soup.find('table',{"class" : "vcalendar ical"})
for r in calendar.findAll('tr'):
#   print ''.join(r.findAll('abbr',text=True))
#   print ''.join(r.findAll('strong',text=True))
    print r.find('abbr')
    print r.find('strong')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`soup.find('abbr').string` should work fine. There must be something wrong with `date`.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

doc = '<abbr class="dtstart" title="2012-11-16T00:00:00-05:00">November 16, 2012</abbr>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

for abbr in soup.findAll('abbr'):
    print abbr.string
```

**Result:**

```
November 16, 2012
```

---

**Update based on code added to question:**

You can't use the `text` parameter like that.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#arg-text

> text is an argument that lets you search for NavigableString objects
>   instead of Tags

Either you're looking for text nodes, or you're looking for tags. A text node can't have a tag name.

Maybe you want `''.join([el.string for el in r.findAll('strong')])`?

Comment: Just don't use `text=True` when searching for elements. Find the elements you want and then use the `.string` property of those elements.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that `date` is `None`. You haven't shown enough code to say why that is so. Indeed, using the code you posted in the most straight-forward way should work:

```
import BeautifulSoup

content='<abbr class="dtstart" title="2012-11-16T00:00:00-05:00">November 16, 2012</abbr>'
r=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(content)
date=r.find('abbr')
print(date.string)
# November 16, 2012
```